# can't publish page on django-cms due to "IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint"

Tags: python, django, postgresql, web-applications, django-cms

In my django-cms website I am having some trouble when publishing pages via admin interface. Below the stacktrace:

```
    DEBUG 2013-06-07 14:09:31,562 util 32222 140056576640768 (0.000) SELECT DISTINCT "menus_cachekey"."key" FROM "menus_cachekey" WHERE "menus_cachekey"."site" = 1 ; args=(1,)
DEBUG 2013-06-07 14:09:31,565 util 32222 140056576640768 (0.000) DELETE FROM "menus_cachekey" WHERE "menus_cachekey"."site" = 1 ; args=(1,)
DEBUG 2013-06-07 14:09:31,570 util 32222 140056576640768 (0.001) INSERT INTO "cms_page" ("created_by", "changed_by", "parent_id", "creation_date", "changed_date", "publication_date", "publication_end_date", "in_navigation", "soft_root", "reverse_id", "navigation_extenders", "published", "template", "site_id", "login_required", "limit_visibility_in_menu", "level", "lft", "rght", "tree_id", "publisher_is_draft", "publisher_public_id", "publisher_state") VALUES (E'roberto', E'roberto', NULL, E'2013-06-07 12:09:31.567872+00:00', E'2013-06-07 12:09:31.567989+00:00', E'2013-06-07 12:09:26.553334+00:00', NULL, false, false, NULL, NULL, true, E'unicms/departments_and_groups/department_detail.html', 1, false, NULL, 0, 1, 2, 9, false, 9, 0) RETURNING "cms_page"."id"; args=(u'roberto', u'roberto', None, u'2013-06-07 12:09:31.567872+00:00', u'2013-06-07 12:09:31.567989+00:00', u'2013-06-07 12:09:26.553334+00:00', None, False, False, None, None, True, u'unicms/departments_and_groups/department_detail.html', 1, False, None, 0, 1, 2, 9, False, 9, 0)
ERROR 2013-06-07 14:09:31,571 base 32222 140056576640768 Internal Server Error: /admin/cms/page/9/change-status/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/roberto/.virtualenvs/ve_news2_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/roberto/.virtualenvs/ve_news2_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 91, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/roberto/.virtualenvs/ve_news2_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 89, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/roberto/.virtualenvs/ve_news2_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 202, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/roberto/.virtualenvs/ve_news2_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 25, in _wrapper
    return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/roberto/.virtualenvs/ve_news2_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/http.py", line 41, in inner
    return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/roberto/.virtualenvs/ve_news2_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 21, in bound_func
    return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2)
  File "/home/roberto/.virtualenvs/ve_news2_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/admin/pageadmin.py", line 1062, in change_status
    success = method()
  File "/home/roberto/.virtualenvs/ve_news2_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/models/pagemodel.py", line 419, in publish
    public_page.save()
  File "/home/roberto/.virtualenvs/ve_news2_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/models/pagemodel.py", line 367, in save
    super(Page, self).save(**kwargs)
  File "/home/roberto/.virtualenvs/ve_news2_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mptt/models.py", line 696, in save
    super(MPTTModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/roberto/.virtualenvs/ve_news2_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 546, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/home/roberto/.virtualenvs/ve_news2_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/models/pagemodel.py", line 384, in save_base
    ret = super(Page, self).save_base(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/roberto/.virtualenvs/ve_news2_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 650, in save_base
    result = manager._insert([self], fields=fields, return_id=update_pk, using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/home/roberto/.virtualenvs/ve_news2_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 215, in _insert
    return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
  File "/home/roberto/.virtualenvs/ve_news2_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1661, in insert_query
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/home/roberto/.virtualenvs/ve_news2_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 937, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/roberto/.virtualenvs/ve_news2_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 41, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/roberto/.virtualenvs/ve_news2_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 56, in execute
    six.reraise(utils.IntegrityError, utils.IntegrityError(*tuple(e.args)), sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/home/roberto/.virtualenvs/ve_news2_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 54, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "cms_page_publisher_public_id_key"
```

The department model is quite simple

```
class Department(models.Model):
    research_area = models.ManyToManyField('research_area.ResearchArea', blank=True,
                                           related_name='departments')  # many-to-many
    products = models.ManyToManyField('products_activities.Product', blank=True, related_name="departments")
    employees = models.ManyToManyField('staff.Person', through='department.PersonDepartmentMembership',
                                       related_name='departments')  # TODO WARNINGS
    research_groups = models.ManyToManyField('group.Group', blank=True, related_name='departments',
                                             through="department.GroupDepartmentMembership")
    page = models.OneToOneField(Page, blank=True, related_name='department', null=True)


    name = models.CharField(_('department name'), max_length=50, default=_('Department name'))
    description = models.TextField(_('department description'))
    logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='img/departments')
    address = models.CharField(_('office address'), max_length=255)
    post_address = models.CharField(_('post address'), max_length=255)
    telephone = PhoneNumberField(blank=True, null=True)
    fax = PhoneNumberField(blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ('view_department', _('View department')),
        )

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('pages-details-by-slug', kwargs={'slug': self.page.get_slug('en')})
```

Not all pages are affected by this problem. In my cms I have set up an automatic page creation system. When the user creates a department, a new page is set up.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Department)
def _on_save_department_create_link_to_page(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    from cms.api import assign_user_to_page, add_plugin, publish_page
    if created:  # create department Page
        from cms.api import create_page

        instance.page = create_page(
            title=instance.name,
            language='en',
            published=False,
            template=settings.CMS_TEMPLATE_DEPARTMENT[0],
        )

        # add some plugins...

        editors = instance.employees.filter(cmsuser__groups__name__exact='web')
        for e in editors:
            assign_user_to_page(instance.page, e)
        instance.page.save()
```

I have found on the internet [some blog article](http://www.vlent.nl/weblog/2011/05/06/integrityerror-duplicate-key-value-violates-unique-constraint/) pointing that his may be due to succesive south migrations. I hardly doubt it, as I have the error without applying any data migration as well.

Any feedback will be very much appreciated! Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 2):

Becuse of the change in how moderation runs when upgrading django-cms you'll need to run:

```
python manage.py cms moderator on
```

See http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.4.0/advanced/cli.html#moderation-commands for more info.

If you're still struggling with some of the pages still giving that constraint error you'll need to open a django shell:

```
python manage.py dbshell
```

And then delete the problem with SQL

```
delete from cms_page where publisher_public_id=79;
```

Comment: Good one. I hope it will be useful next time we upgrade our cms :-)

Answer (score 1):

There's a constraint in your database table `cms_page` that's called `cms_page_publisher_public_id_key`. A constraint can specify many things, but is usually used to keep values unique. In your case it seems to be something with uniqueness too:

```
duplicate key value violates unique constraint
```

In your model I can't see anything you specified as unique, but maybe you changed your code over time and forgot to change your database table accordingly?

Check what your table `cms_page` looks like in the database and what the constraint `cms_page_publisher_public_id_key` exaclty does. Then you'll probably find the cause.

Comment: Thanks for your answer rednaw, I had already checked the DB. But finally, setting published=True on the page creation seems to have solved the issue.